# Automatically Update state when i hit function which has new value that i want to add in data

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

1. I have Add_Product Page where I'm adding a product with the 4/5 parameters like name, desc, etc.
2. on the other hand, I have a product page where I'm showing all that product which are there in my DataBase.
3. now what I wanted to do is that when I hit that Add product button the other page which has all product data got update automatic and that should show me that new product with all other products.
4. By the way, I'm using flatlist to show my data.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I recommend using some global state manager like redux or contextApi.

If you are using react-navigation, you also can send a callback through the navigation parameter that triggers a list state update on the previous Page with the new product payload.

something like that with hooks:

```
const Page1 = ({})=>{
   const navigation = useNavigation();
   const [productList, setProductList] = useState([]);

   navigation.navigate('Page2', {
      addProduct: (product) => setproductList(lastState => [product, ...lastState ])} 
}
```

now. just call addProduct inside the Page2 with navigation router

```
const Page2 = ({})=>{
   const router = useRouter();
   const {addProduct} = router.params 
}
```

Comment: I'm not using hook I'm using class components. please refer me more.